# azure data factory pipeline run history into excel

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I wanted to export all the Pipeline run times date into an excel .
Is there a way i can export the run activity of all the pipeline run into Excel for Azure Data Factory ?.Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory()` to get that info by using [Python SDK](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-datafactory/) and then save it into an excel.

The API document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.operations.pipelinerunsoperations?view=azure-python#query-by-factory-resource-group-name--factory-name--filter-parameters----kwargs-